# Watchkit: table with two templates in dynamic rows

Tags: ios, watchkit, apple-watch, wkinterfacetable

How to instantiate two different templates of dynamic row in WKInterfaceTable?  For only one template I use functions

```
 [self.stocksTable setNumberOfRows: self.stocksData.count withRowType:@"TableRow"];
 TableRow *row = [self.stocksTable rowControllerAtIndex:i];
```

Question: How to have 2 types of row?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You want [`-[WKInterfaceTable setRowTypes:]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/WatchKit/Reference/WKInterfaceTable_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/WKInterfaceTable/setRowTypes:):

```
[self.myTable setRowTypes:@[@"RowType1", @"RowType2"]];
MyRowType1Controller *row1 = [self.myTable rowControllerAtIndex:0];
MyRowType2Controller *row2 = [self.myTable rowControllerAtIndex:1];
```

Comment: Thank, I couldn't get that we need to specify manually array of types for each row before. Works for me!

Answer (score 0):

Building on @dave-delong's (correct!) answer, most tables will have a mix of row types, and the array must reflect that. For example, a table with a header, 4 rows of info, and a footer, would require an array looking something like this:

```
NSArray *rowTypes = @[@"headerRowType", @"infoRowType", @"infoRowType", @"infoRowType", @"infoRowType", @"footerRowType"];
[self.myTable setRowTypes:rowTypes];
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift solution, for case with dynamic cell count:

```
    let notificationRowTypes = Array(repeating: "notificationRow", count: watchNotifications.count)
    let notificationDateRowTypes = Array(repeating: "notificationDateRow", count: watchNotifications.count)
    let rowTypes = mergeArrays(notificationDateRowTypes, notificationRowTypes)
    noficationsTable.setRowTypes(rowTypes)
    updateTableRowsContent()


func mergeArrays<T>(_ arrays:[T] ...) -> [T] {
    return (0..<arrays.map{$0.count}.max()!)
        .flatMap{i in arrays.filter{i<$0.count}.map{$0[i]} }
}

func updateTableRowsContent() {
    let numberOfRows = noficationsTable.numberOfRows
    for index in 0..<numberOfRows {
        switch index % 2 == 0 {
        case true:
            guard let controller = noficationsTable.rowController(at: index) as? NotificationDateRowController else { continue }
            controller.notification = watchNotifications[index / 2]
        case false:
            guard let controller = noficationsTable.rowController(at: index) as? NotificationRowController else { continue }
            controller.notification = watchNotifications[index / 2]
        }
    }
}
```